# Do not allow Enter Key to make a new line in MultiLine TextBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, multiline

I set the property `Multiline=true;`.

I do not want to allow the Enter Key to make a new line.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Then why do you have MultiLine?

Comment: cause input text is long and see easily. And Enter key to insert data

Comment: Are you looking to prevent editing? ReadOnly property can do that

Comment: no man, can edit and input text but I no want newline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That could be as simple as listening to `TextChanged` event and then executing the following line inside it:

```
txtYourTextBox.Text = txtYourTextBox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

This solution involves some screen flicker though. A better way is to prevent it entirely by listening to `KeyDown` event:

```
private void txtYourTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am quite late to the party, but for others who read this I would mention that there is a property named `TextBox.AcceptsReturn` (Boolean).

Just set it in the properties window of the TextBox.

I had the same problem just the other way round: I had a multiline TextBox, but it didn't allow me to enter Returns.

Further information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn?view=net-5.0