# ToolstripTextBox editing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ContextMenuStrip with a ToolstripTextBox in a drop down menu
I want the user to input a number in the Textbox and when he finishes he should press "Enter" to indicate that he finished editing (the textbox should show the number but not be in editing mode)
Also, after the user presses enter i want to update an outer class which should hold this value  but i cant reach this class in the context of a KeyDown event handler.

Is there a way to change the EventArgs received in the event handler?
How do i identify the "Enter" pressed by the user and how should i modify the 
ToolstripTextBox to show the number but not in editing mode (the caret is not in the ToolstripTextBox )

Comment: have you checked this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700992/do-not-allow-enter-key-to-make-a-new-line-in-multiline-textbox-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for